# How to properly get the value contained inside a section using XPath?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

having the following HTML (snippet grabbed from the web page I wanted to **scrape**):

```
<div class="ulListContainer">
    <section class="stockUpdater">
        <ul class="column4">
            <li>
                <img src="1.png" alt="">
                <strong>
                    Buy*
                </strong>
                <strong>
                    Sell*
                </strong>
            </li>
            <li>
                <header>
                    $USD
                </header>
                <span class="">              
                    20.90
                </span>
                <span class="">               
                     23.15
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

how do I get the **2nd li 1st span** value using XPath? The result should be `20.90`.

I have tried the following `//div[@class="ulListContainer"]/section/ul[1]/li[2]/span[1]` but I am not getting any values. I must said this is being used from a Google Sheet and using the function `IMPORTXML` (not sure what version of XPath it does uses) can I get some help?

**Update**

Apparently Google Sheets does not support such "complex" XPath expression since it seems to work fine:

[image]

**Update 1**
As requested I've shared the Google Sheet I am using to test this, [here is the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uW7RyFsYeNw9GHr7Eq1r8E0iwJZCTlhyXl3E3zXQFJ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: In order to correctly test your situation, can you provide the URL you are using?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with URL and example of desired output

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide a sample of your sheet or at least the HTML page to make the ```IMPORTXML``` request so that we can test this in our environment and try to figure out where the issue is located? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @everyone I have added a link to the OP, you've edit permissions in there, let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//li[contains(text(),'USD')]/span[1]")
```

[image: USD]

Removing `section` from your original XPath will work too :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//div[@class='ulListContainer']/ul[1]/li[2]/span[1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IMPORTXML("URL","//span[1]")
```

Change URL to the actual website link/URL

Comment: does not work, it returns more data from what I really need